# Return ID if record exist, else Insert and return ID

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have the below C# code to check if the record does not exist, insert and return id. But also I need if the record exists, it return the value. What change should I make to C# and SQL part for this to happen? Database is sQL server. Do I still have to use ExecuteScalar() for this?

```
con.Open();

// Insert ClinRefFileTypeMaster
string command1 = string.Format(
    "if NOT exists (select * from [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] where [ClinRefTypeName] = '{0}') Insert into [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] ([ClinRefTypeName]) output INSERTED.[ClinRefTypeID] VALUES('{0}')",
      dataToParse[i][0]
      );
SqlCommand ClinRefFileTypeMaster = new SqlCommand(command1, con);

// check if there is an value 
object checkValue = ClinRefFileTypeMaster.ExecuteScalar(); 

if (checkValue != null)
    ClinRefFileTypeId = (int)checkValue;
```

Comment: Probably you need the MERGE statement

Comment: Maybe split the statements. Only insert in the if-block. select outside. SQL is pretty good with caching, if you've just inserted something selecting it is probably going to be very fast. Also the query is hard to read, please make into a multi-line string by starting it with @.

Comment: This look [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) unaware.

Comment: Similar solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172842/executing-merge-statement-via-c-sharp-sqlcommand-not-working)

Comment: Or use a DECLARE recordId int; and then SELECT recordId = idColumn FROM tbl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. 1) You can do it all in inline Sql 2) you can do it all in stored proc. 3) You can do it all in code but split the code as this code is frankly doing too much. In general I would avoid insert/query in the same method.

*Also try to use SqlParameters instead of building the query as string concat.*

I would propose something like this which makes the code a bit more readable

```
    public int InsertAndRetrieveClientRefId(string clientRefTypeName)
    {
        int id = GetIdIfRecordExists(clientRefTypeName);

        if (id == 0)
        { 
            // insert logic here

            id = GetIdIfRecordExists(clientRefTypeName);
        }

        return id;
    }

    public int GetIdIfRecordExists(string clientRefTypeName)
    {
        int id = 0;

        string command = "select id from ClinRefFileTypeMaster where ClinRefTypeName = @ClinRefTypeName";
        SqlParameter nameParameter = new SqlParameter("@ClinRefTypeName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10) { Value = clientRefTypeName };

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(newParameter);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                int.TryParse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out id);
            }
        }

        return id;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as using store procedure was not an option for me. I think you only forgot to add the nameParameter  to the command ! I did that and it worked great.

Comment: glad it worked. I've updated the answer to add the parameter to the command.

Answer (score 2):

A stored procedure to do all the stuff for you would look something like.....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Get_ClinRefTypeID
  @ClinRefTypeName  VARCHAR(100),
  @ClinRefTypeID    INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NewID TABLE(ClinRefTypeID INT);

  SELECT @ClinRefTypeID = [ClinRefTypeID]
  FROM [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] 
  where [ClinRefTypeName] = @ClinRefTypeName;

  IF (@ClinRefTypeID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] ([ClinRefTypeName]) 
        OUTPUT inserted.[ClinRefTypeID]  INTO @NewID(ClinRefTypeID)
        VALUES(@ClinRefTypeName)

        SELECT @ClinRefTypeID = [ClinRefTypeID] FROM @NewID
    END

END
```

And your C# code would look something like.....

```
con.Open();

// Insert ClinRefFileTypeMaster
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Get_ClinRefTypeID", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClinRefTypeID", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ClinRefTypeName", dataToParse));

// get the value back from the output parameter 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int ClinRefTypeName = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ClinRefTypeID"].Value);
```

Comment: Yeah, I strongly recomand this way! Much safer and way easier to mantain.

Answer (score 1):

Youll need to add an IF EXISTS clause to the SQL statement as well, checking for the same conditions, and providing logic to return a value.

It seems using ExecuteReader would be better if you need it to return the value from the database.

2¢
I personally would split the logic into two queries and run the If statement within c# checking if the value is in the database, then updating the database else returning a value from the database

```
conn.open()
int CheckDb;
String Command1 = "select * from [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] where [ClinRefTypeName] = @ClinRefFileTypeId";
using (SqlCommand ClinRefFileTypeMaster = new SqlCommand(command1, con);
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClinRefFileTypeId", {0});
         CheckDb = (int)ClinRefFileTypeMaster.ExecuteScalar();
     }
If (CheckDb != 0)
    //Logic for returning the value from the database
Else
    //Here you can request user check data or insert the value into the database.
```

Answer (score 1):

do all this in database i.e in store procedure

```
if not exists (select 1 from  [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] where [ClinRefTypeName] =@name)
begin
Insert into [ClinRefFileTypeMaster] ([ClinRefTypeName]) values (@name) 
end
else
begin
select (as desired) from ClinRefFileTypeMaster where where [ClinRefTypeName] =@name
end
```

this will either insert new record or it will select already inserted information

Answer (score 1):

if you want to perform Instert operation, I think its better you call a stored procedure and write your query in the procedure. It will be safer.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("procedureName",con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@value1”, txtValue1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@value2”, Value2);
int value = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

---

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE FieldValue='') 
BEGIN
SELECT TableID FROM Table WHERE FieldValue=''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE(FieldValue) VALUES('')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS TableID
END
```

If you want to pass the querystring, you can call select query and if it returns `null` perform a insert opeartion and use `scope_Identity()` to get the `ID`

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(val1, val2, val3 ...) 
VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3...);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```